# click function Jquery Timing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a problem that when i'm clicking my thumb-units it reloads the page it had to open but it is opening for 0.5 sec and then the thumb units returns again, what's wrong?

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    workSlider();
});

function workSlider() {

  $('.thumb-unit').click(function() {
    $('.work-slider').css('left' , '-100%');
    $('.work-container').show();
  });

  $('.work-return').click(function() {
    $('.work-slider').css('left' , '0%');
    $('.work-container').hide(800);

  });
}
```

here's my html, it should show the work container

```
<section class="alt-section section-work">
    <div class="work-slider">
        <div class="thumb-wrap">
            <div class="thumb-container">
                {% for project in site.data.settings.projects %}
                <a href="" class="thumb-unit" style="background-image: url(/assets/img/work/{{project.folder}}/thumb.jpg);">

                    <div class="thumb-overlay">
                        <strong>{{ project.name }}</strong>
                        <div class="zoom-icon"></div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="work-wrap">
            <div class="work-container">
                <div class="work-return">{% include icons/icon-back.html %}</div>
                <h4 color="black">Hey dude</h4>
                <div style="width: 600px; height: 500px; background: #ccc;">
                <iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Y9dhSgnRl0s" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
                <p>welcome to my world</p>
                <div style="width: 600px; height: 500px; background: #ccc;"></div>
                <p>welcome to my world</p>
                <div style="width: 600px; height: 500px; background: #ccc;"></div>
                <p>welcome to my world</p>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: 1) show the html, 2) what is it supposed to do?

Comment: You should update the question instead of posting an _answer_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be off base but since the `.thumb-unit` is an anchor tag, I believe you have to prevent the default event which is navigation, and with an empty `href` attribute should be to reload the page. Try this:

```
$('.thumb-unit').click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('.work-slider').css('left' , '-100%');
    $('.work-container').show();
});
```

Since `.work-return` is a div, it is not necessary to add the same snippet to it since there is no default event that you need to prevent.

Answer (score 1):

I think your page might be reloading on click because your not preventing the default behavior of your link.

Try this:

```
  $('.thumb-unit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.work-slider').css('left' , '-100%');
    $('.work-container').show();
  });

  $('.work-return').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.work-slider').css('left' , '0%');
    $('.work-container').hide(800);

  });
```